# visual studio corrupt projects in solution after TFS map

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have on TFS that projects in folders:

> \root
>
> ```
> \website1
> \website2
> \libraries
>          class project1
>          class project2
>          class project3
> ```

when I map by TFS to local every folder and project map ok,
but after open by visual studio all project below website1 was move to website1 folder ;/

Can anybody explain me this VS behavior or how to repair it ?

p.s. after close visual studio sln file missed and I must map everything ones again ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to minimise the number of folder mappings that you set up - a good project will need only one, to say where the root folder of the source code tree will be stored on your local hard drive. In your case, this should be something like:

```
$/root -> C:\MyCode
```

The more mappings you add, the less correspondence you will see between the source control file structure and your local disk structure, and things can get messy very fast.

(Another place that can cause problems is that if you add files within the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, it will often copy the files to the location you're adding them in your solution, rather than referencing them from their original location on your hard drive. But this doesn't sound like it relatesto your question)

Once you have set up the solution, make sure you save it (File -> Save All is useful for ensuring this is done) and you may need to manually add the .sln file into source control and check it in to get it all into TFS.

Comment: Thank You, I use Your tips ;)